# Pagination на сайте и динамическая база данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

В своем сайте реализую стандартную подгрузку данных при прокрутке страницы вниз. 
Для реализации такого решения естественно на ум приходит применения обычного `LIMIT`  в запросах к базе данных со смещением.

Но у меня возникает вопрос:

> Каким образом грамотно учитывать измененные в процессе данные?

К примеру у нас есть `400` записей о сотрудниках в базе данных. 
У сотрудников есть поле `is_work` (Работает)
Страница при открытии запрашивает первую партию работающих сотрудников.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE is_work = TRUE LIMIT 0, 20
```

После того как мы получили первую страницу у нас в базе могли произойти изменения поля `is_work` у некоторых строк. Эти изменения могли быть сделаны как нами, так и другими пользователями.

И получается что следующий запрос с использованием `LIMIT 20, 20` вернет нам уже не те данные которые мы хотели бы получить. (Или те, в зависимости от того, где будут произведены изменения)

Есть ли какое либо стандартное решение данного вопроса?

**Замечание:**

Эту задачу я могу решить несколькими не очень красивыми способами, включая получения всего массива, использования конструкции `NOT IN` и т.д. (Под некрасивыми я имею ввиду все способы, реализация которых будет тормозить прямо пропорционально росту базы).

Comment: а просто сайт поставить на обслуживание и сделать его не доступным - это вариант ?

Comment: Нет. Не вариант.

Comment: Надо бы словами определится, что вообще должен видеть пользователь. На первой странице что то удалено, запрошена вторая страница. что на ней выводить, как будто на первой странице было 19 записей ? На первую страницу в саме начало добавлена запись, как со второй страницей быть, она все равно не должна показать запись которая "вылезла" с 1й и что при этом с новой, ее не показывать, она как бы на 1й ? По моему как не сделай, поведение все равно будет казаться странным. И что бы делать в идеале надо в БД фиксировать дату/время изменения is_work и пробовать от этого плясать

Comment: Если ухитриться отображать "снимок" состояния, это породит свои проблемы. Пользователи будут возмущаться: как так, есть новые данные, а мы не видим. Или: почему вы показываете запись как is_work, а она уже не is_work! Так что лучше принять как есть: да, иногда записи будут смещаться относительно границы страницы. Понять и простить, я считаю.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Решение с уменьшенным количество строк на второй странице меня вполне устраивает. Однако вопрос по поводу этого - как отследить это? Вот натурально как вычислить что выборка будет меньше, и получить те самые 19 строк. Спасибо